# Creating a verification key for cookies

Tags: php, security, cookies

I've working on secure cookies for all users and a fast way to verify them.

This is what i come up with:

When you register a user a salt is generated into the database for each user.

When you log in set these two cookies:

`$_COOKIE["key"]` and `$_COOKIE["user"]`

`$_COOKIE["user"]` is the ID of the user that logged in.

The `$_COOKIE["key"]` is set like this: `sha1(sha1($id).sha1($salt));`

and then to verify the cookies i created this function:

```
public function check_cookie(){


    //CHECK IF THE COOKIE IS MATCHING THE HASHKEY AND IF USER IS CONTAINING NUMBERS
    if(sha1(sha1($_COOKIE["user"]).sha1($salt)) != $_COOKIE["key"] || 
!is_numeric($_COOKIE["user"])){

        //REMOVE COOKIES 
        setcookie('user', null, -1);
        setcookie('key', null, -1);

        return FALSE;

    } else {

        return TRUE;

    }

}
```

Is this a secure way to do it? Do you see any fault in this way of structure?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For first why is isset condition as second (what won't be executed)? If cookies are not generated, first condition is to check key but it is unnecessary if you don't have any cookies yet.

Comment: Oh forgot to move that. I've just payed attention to the cookie check. That doesn't need to be in this question

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This scheme is about as secure as putting password into the cookie: If someone steals the cookie once, he will be logged in into your service indefinitely. The only advantage is that if the user reuses his/her password it will not be leaked to the attacker.

Comment: This link describes useful 'auto login' practices using cookies and a database table. [persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/). Internet search 'php login remember me' provides lots of useful links.